# PDF file not downloading as pdf on .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, download

so I have a code that previews a PDF file using this code:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        //text box holds the path to the original pdf file in a folder
        Byte[] Thisbuffer = client.DownloadData(TextBox.Text);

        if (Thisbuffer!= null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", Thisbuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(Thisbuffer);
        }
```

It views PDF file fine in chrome, IE, and Edge but on chrome when I do a download using these options:
[image: See image]

It downloads the file as .aspx not .pdf. This is only happening in chrome not in IE or Edge.

I have tried `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myPDFfile.pdf");` and this auto downloads the file wont allow it to be able to view before download. 
Any help is appreciated thank!

Comment: You can find the answer here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/mU19HrhqBXc

Comment: @Shanjee thanks for the comment but as you can see in that example it is asking for content type which is clearly specified in my code, I even tried it with the http client it didn't work

Comment: @SimpleCode What is reason for this I don't know, either I have no explanation for this, However adding two line of code worked for me:              Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's built in PDF viewer download button points to the PDF's origin URL, so in your case the aspx page. A potential solution to this issue would to create an new aspx page that loads the PDF on page_load, and then target the new page.

Not sure how your original code block is being called, but you should be able to either insert the target page with an `<a>` anchor tag or use `Response.Redirect()`.

Example target page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["RequestedPath"] != null)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        //text box holds the path to the original pdf file in a folder
        Byte[] Thisbuffer = client.DownloadData(Request.QueryString["RequestedPath"]);

        if (Thisbuffer!= null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=myPDFfile.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", Thisbuffer.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(Thisbuffer);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 
        }
    }
}
```